# Commenting system for RoR Blogging Platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, comments

I'm trying to design a comment system for my RoR blogging site, and I am having some conceptual problems with the architecture.  As far as models are concerned, I have Blogposts, Users, and Comments.

- A **User** has_many **Blogposts**
- A **Blogpost** belongs_to one **User**
- A **Blogpost** has_many **Comments**
- A **Comment** *may or may not belong* to a registered **User** (I want people not registered with the site to be able to comment as well).

My question is this: in order to enforce the link between a comment and a blogpost, I create each new comment (**@comment**) through the blogpost association (**@blogpost.comments.build**(:args)).  However, I do not know how to associate a particular registered User with his/her comment.  I left the **user_id** attribute OUT of the **attr_accessible** for the **Comment** model because I wanted to prevent the possibility of people attributing comments to the wrong users.

Any ideas on how best to implement a commenting system with such a relation?  Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
User has_many comments
Comment belongs_to user
```

In your controller when saving the comment, you can simply do:

```
@comment.user = current_user if current_user
@comment.save
```

If the comment is done by an unregistered user `@comment.user` just stays empty.

Comment: Thanks, Mischa!  Does this mean that I can use my controller to set the user_id for comment created by the blogpost association, whether or not it's listed as attr_accessible under the comment model? Is it possible, or even recommended, that I have "Comment belongs_to User" if it already belongs_to Blogpost?

Comment: Yes, if you do the assignment like this it doesn't matter if `user_id` is `attr_accessible` or not. Of course it is possible to have `Comment belongs_to user`. It really doesn't matter that comment belongs to blogpost already. Comments can belong to many different things. IMO, my answer is the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Using my rails console, I created a sample comment through @blogpost.comments.build(:args), which left the @comment.user_id attribute under the new comment as nil.  But when I tried to assign a :user_id through update_attributes, the development log gave me the following error: "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id."  Any ideas?

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I forgot to specify that Comment belongs_to User.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can just have an association :

```
User has_many comments through blog_posts
```

So, now you can do :

```
current_user.comments
```

Another way to do it is via blog_post:

```
current_user.blog_post.comments
```

Moreover, you can use the nice act_as_commentable plugin :)

https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable

Comment: Thanks SpyrosP!  I have a quick question: What will current_user.blog_post.comments give me?  Will it be all the comments by current_user, or all the comments for blog_post, or all the comments by current_user under the blog_post?

Comment: blog_post is a user's blog post. So it will give you the comments of that post. The way this is typically done is that you get current_user.blog_posts. This now is an array of all user posts. Now, you can have an each iteration for all the posts and get the comments of every blog post.

Comment: No, it will give you all the comments (by anyone) on blog posts made by current_user. It seems Spyros didn't read your question thoroughly.

Comment: It's the same idea whether a user is registered or not. It will just be a guest user or so. The comments of a user can be received by a simple find_by_user_id(or find on guest name or registered name). The important thing to have is the association i describe in my answer. After that, you can get any user comment, on any occasion you want.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what he is asking.

Comment: What do you think he's asking that i don't answer ?

Comment: His question is very simple: he wants to know how to assign a user to a comment. All you are talking about is getting the comments of a blog post made by the current user. It's a completely different thing. Please read his question again carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have **user_id** as **attr_accessible** if you have access to the currently logged in user in your save or post new comment methods.

If they aren't logged in then you expect current user to be empty / false.

This should be available if you're using any of the authentication plugins such as authlogic or devise. In my experience with authlogic you typically have a current_user method in your ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController
helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

private
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
  end
end
```

[Above code from the Authlogic quick example](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)

Comment: Thanks Lummo! Indeed I do have a current_user available to me through a sessionsHelper.  Does this mean that, as Mischa pointed out, I can use my controller to set the user_id for comment created by the blogpost association, whether or not it's listed as attr_accessible under the comment model?

Comment: That's right! Using attr_accessible will only effect whether the attribute can be set by mass assignment (usually from new) but it doesn't stop you from assigning it individually. There's a great explanation of attr_accessible and the reasons for using it on ASCIIcasts - http://asciicasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can add an association between Comment and User, then create the comment with current_user:

```
# User.rb
has_many :comments

# Comment
belongs_to :user
```

Setting up the associations only really adds the association methods, so there's no problem with creating Comment without a logged in user. You don't want to build the comment off of current_user as `current_user.comments.create(...)`, because that will throw a NilClass error if nobody is logged in.

```
@user = current_user # @user should be nil if commenter is not logged in
# be fancy and use a block
@blogpost.comments.create(params[:comment]) do |c|
  c.user = @user
end
```

As long as there is no validation for User in Comment, the nil user should just pass  through without trouble.